# Error specifying OpenSSL config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to install an SSL certificate on an EC2 Load Balancer.  Following this guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html

- I have OpenSSL installed (in Windows)
- running command-prompt as admin
- I'm on the step "Before you use OpenSSL commands, you must configure the operating system so that it has information about the location of the OpenSSL install point."

> set OpenSSL_HOME= C:\OpenSSL-Win32
>
> set OpenSSL_CONFIG= C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg
>
> set Path=%Path%;%OpenSSL_HOME%\bin

- Does it matter what directory I'm "in" when I run those commands?
- The Amazon guide says to "set OpenSSL_CONFIG= ..." but I've seen in multiple examples that it should be "set OpenSSL_CONF= ..." so is it "CONFIG" or "CONF"?
- After that it says to:

> openssl genrsa 2048 > your-private-key-filename.pem

- so, I CD to "C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin" and then I run "openssl genrsa 2048 > new_key.pem"
- At this point 1 of 2 things happens.

  - If I used "OpenSSL_CONFIG" like it says in the guide, then I get the warning: "WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf" however the .pem file DOES get created anyways.
  - If I used "OpenSSL_CONF" then I get the following error:

> 4848:error:0200107B:system library:fopen:Unknown error:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:169:fopen('C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg','rb')
>   4848:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:174:
>   4848:error:0E078002:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:system lib:.\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:199:

- Then I move on to the step to create a CSR, and I get a similar situation

  - If I used "OpenSSL_CONFIG" then I get this error:

    > WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
    >   Unable to load config info from /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
  - If I used "OpenSSL_CONF" then I get this error:

    > 4848:error:0200107B:system library:fopen:Unknown error:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:1
    >   69:fopen(' C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg','rb')
    >   4848:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c
    >   :174:
    >   4848:error:0E078002:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:system lib:.\crypto\con
    >   f\conf_def.c:199:

I am totally stuck at this point.  I'm unable to create the CSR no matter what I do.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm pretty sure that the Amazon guide is incorrect. "set OpenSSL_CONFIG" doesn't seem to have any effect.  But "set OpenSSL_CONF" definitely does have an effect.  This makes me wonder what else is incorrect or missing in the Amazon guide...

EDIT:
well... I just skipped the first three steps where you set openssl_home, openssl_config and the path, and everything worked fine.  so... not sure what the point of those steps are, because they certainly didn't help.

Comment: I also face a similar issue, where using OPENSSL_CONF brings up an unknown error from openssl. Did you find any solution to this? I see your question is a bit old...

Comment: I think I just did what it says in the edit; skipped those first couple of steps and everything worked.  Sorry I can't be of much help, I don't have a very clear memory of what I did.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem, what happened was that I did not set `OPENSSL_CONF` correctly, i.e.:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF="D:\openssl.cnf"      # did not work :(
set OPENSSL_CONF=D:\openssl.cnf        # worked! (without the quotes)
```

What I see in your post is that you have a *single space character* after the equals sign on the `set` command: `OPENSSL_CONF= your-file-here.cnf`.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is now sloved